# How can i display the video current and duration time like this 00:25/00:30?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I want to display the video `currentTime` and `duration` in a different format.

The way it displays it now is:

***0:9 / 0:33***

I want it to display it like this:

***00:09 / 00:33***

Or if the video duration is more than 1 minute

***03:10 / 12:27***

the current code i have right now

```
    video.on('timeupdate', function() {

        // Set to minute and seconds
        var time = video[0].currentTime;
        var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);   
        var seconds = Math.floor(time);

        // Set the current play value
        currentTimer.text(minutes + ':' + seconds);
    });

    video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {

        // Set to minute and seconds
        var time = video[0].duration;
        var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);   
        var seconds = Math.floor(time);  

        // Set the video duration
        durationTimer.text(minutes + ':' + seconds);
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code should do what you want :

```js
function format(s) {
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    m = (m >= 10) ? m : "0" + m;
    s = Math.floor(s % 60);
    s = (s >= 10) ? s : "0" + s;
    return m + ":" + s;
}

alert(format(120));
alert(format(250));
alert(format(31));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It does what i want. I wish i could come up with this awnser myself :P

Answer (score 0):

```js
</body>
<script>
 var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-element'),
 meta = document.getElementById('meta');
 
 myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
 var duration = myVideoPlayer.duration;
 meta.innerHTML = "Duration is " + duration.toFixed(2) + " seconds."
 });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="col-md-8" id='player'>
     <video style="width:100%;height:auto;"  id='video-element' controls preload controlsList="nodownload"> <source src="../videos/SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4" id="s1" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'> <source src="../videos/sample1.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'> </video>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="box-body">
      <hr style="margin: 28px 0px 10px;">
      <div class="col-md-12">
       <video width="168" height="94"  id='cc'> <source src="../videos/SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4" id="s1" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'> 
        <source src="../videos/sample1.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'> 
       </video>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="meta"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Use it as i had done. As per requirement modify it. just change the Source of video in Video Tag. It will work 100%